# extract a particular set of data from json file in python

Tags: python, json

i have json file as below .Using python i want a fetch a record for source_name = 'Abc' . How i can achieve it

---json file: file.json

```
[{
    "source_name" :"Abc",
    "target_table"  : "TABLE1",
    "schema": "col1 string, col2 string"
},
{
     "source_name" :"xyz",
    "target_table"  : "TABLE2",
    "schema": "col3 string, col4 string"
}
]
```

final o/p ---

```
{
    "source_name" :"Abc",
    "target_table"  : "TABLE1",
    "schema": "col1 string, col2 string"
}
```

Comment: Load the `json` file into a `list` of `dict`s and iterate over them until you find the desired dictionary. Alternatively, you could use the `filter` function, but using this function is sometimes considered being non-Pythonic.

Comment: You can simply read the file in and use a list comprehension in the form of: **[dtc for dtc in data if dtc["source_name"] == "Abc"]** This will get you the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehensions, which is considered to be more pythonic since the initial data is a list of dictionaries.

```
# using list comprehension 
result = [element for element in json.load(json_file) if element['source_name'] == "Abc"]

# without using list comprehension 
for element in json.load(json_file):
    if element['source_name'] == "Abc":
        print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
data = [{
    "source_name" :"Abc",
    "target_table"  : "TABLE1",
    "schema": "col1 string, col2 string"
},
{
     "source_name" :"xyz",
    "target_table"  : "TABLE2",
    "schema": "col3 string, col4 string"
}
]

l = len(data) 
n = 0
while n < l:
    if (data[n]["source_name"] == "Abc"):
        print(data[n])     
    if n == (l-1):
        break
    n +=1
```

final output

```
{
'source_name': 'Abc', 
'target_table': 'TABLE1', 
'schema': 'col1 string, col2 string'
}
```